# Block links do not work on some blocks

Tags: blocks, navigation

I have created a view that displays a term description, and links to add a post to that term. As you can see from the [Interesting](http://onlinebanter.com/interesting) box here it works quite well.

on some tags though the links dont work at all including the edit node link i have on the view. You can see a non working one [here](http://onlinebanter.com/football).

This happens across all browsers. If i move my block to a position at the bottom of the page it seems to work ok. For the life of me i have no idea whats going on.

Could anyone suggest anything for me?

Comment: mmmmm its seems to work if i clear all the blocks from the same block region and just leave the block itself. I notice that my blocks dont hold their position. Blocks seem to be getting placed on top of blocks. sharing the same space etc. Is there some code i can add to ALL blocks to solve this? clear:both maybe? thanks

Comment: A screenshot that evidences the part of the page you are talking of helps to answer your question, which should be helpful to future readers too.

Comment: @RegGordon .Yes. its correct. clear:both, also you can set witdh to first cell of table .